# Twig pass an include inside of an include

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to pass an include as part of a variable passed in another include. Let me paint a picture:

```
{% include '@AppBundle/P1/template.html.twig' with {
            'body': '<div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h1>Dummy Title</h1>
                    include '@AppBundle/P1/Form/dummyForm.html.twig' with {'form': test_form }
                    '</div>'
            }%}
```

Is this at all possible? I experimented with escaping the strings and concatenations but I always get "punctuation" expected with value "," 404. I really am curious if anyone has encountered such problem and if so, how they overcame it. Thank you all!

Comment: Why don't you place the include inside the included template?

Answer (score 1):

Hummm, to answer your question first, you can use the function instead of the tag:

<kbd>main.twig</kbd>

```
{{ 
    include('@AppBundle/P1/template.html.twig', {
        'body': include('@AppBundle/P1/dummyBody.html.twig')
    })
}}
```

<kbd>dummyBody.html.twig</kbd>

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1>Dummy Title</h1>
    {{ include('@AppBundle/P1/Form/dummyForm.html.twig', {'form': test_form }) }}
</div>
```

[Demo on twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/g3yt24)

---

But you should be aware of [blocks](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html), those are made for this!

<kbd>base.twig</kbd>

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h1>Dummy Title</h1>
    {% block form %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

<kbd>form.twig</kbd>

```
{% extends 'base.twig' %}

{% block form %}
   some form
{% endblock %}
```

Rendering <kbd>form.twig</kbd> will display the same thing, but cleaner and easily reusable.

[Demo on twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/app_dev.php/g3yt24/2)